# Sum of harmonics of the sine/cosine function $ F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N \sin(nx)$.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, summation

I am interested to know if the following sum has a closed form expression:

> $$ F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N \sin(nx) .$$

By 'closed form expression', I mean an expression which may be used to evaluate the function using a number of operations that is independent of $N$. Any of the usual well known functions may be used in the closed form expression.

What if we replace the $\sin()$ by $\cos()$?

Comment: Imaginary part of sum of e^(inx), which is a geometric series

Comment: You may be interested in [Fourier Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html).

Comment: Also, if $N\to\infty$ the series is divergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sin(x) = \text{Im}(e^{ix})$ we have:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N \text{Im}(e^{inx}) = \text{Im}\left(\sum_{n=1}^N e^{inx} \right) = \text{Im}\left(\frac{e^{ix}(e^{Nix} - 1)}{e^{ix} - 1}\right)$$

Now we can simplify this fraction:

$$\frac{e^{ix}(e^{Nix} - 1)}{e^{ix} - 1} = \frac{e^{ix}(e^{Nix} - 1)\cdot (e^{-ix} - 1)}{(e^{ix} - 1)\cdot(e^{-ix} - 1)} = -\frac{(e^{Nix} - 1)(e^{ix} - 1)}{(e^{ix} - 1)(e^{-ix} - 1)}$$

This may not look simpler, but because the denominator is something multiplied by it's conjugate we find that it's real, in fact $2 - 2\cos(x)$, giving:

$$f(x) = -\frac{\text{Im}((e^{Nix} - 1)(e^{ix} - 1))}{(e^{ix} - 1)(e^{-ix} - 1)} = -\frac{\text{Im}((e^{Nix} - 1)(e^{ix} - 1))}{2 - 2\cos(x)}$$

We expand the numerator and find the imaginary part of each separately:

$$\text{Im}((e^{Nix} - 1)(e^{ix} - 1)) =  \text{Im}(e^{Nix + ix} - e^{Nix} - e^{ix} + 1)$$
$$\sin((N+1)x) - \sin(Nx) - \sin(x)$$

Giving final answer:

$$f(x) = \frac{\sin((N+1)x) - \sin(Nx) - \sin(x)}{2\cos(x) - 2}$$

If we replaced $\sin$ by $\cos$ all that would change is replacing $\text{Im}$ with $\text{Re}$, meaning that we can simply replace $\sin$ with $\cos$ in our final answer.

Comment: You could also just extract $e^{ix/2}$ from the denominator and $e^{iNx/2}$ from the numerator. This results in $$Im\left(e^{i(N+1)x/2}\frac{\sin(Nx/2)}{\sin(x/2)}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

One simple way is obtaining
$$-2\sin x~F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N -2\sin x\sin nx$$
then simplify it with telescopic property!